# SQL query (having PatIndex) to EF Linq expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Wondering if you could help in transforming below query in EF Linq expression, my point of confusion is PatIndex function.

```
SELECT b.BuildingNumber, LEFT(b.BuildingNumber, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', l.BuildingNumber+ 't') - 1) numberOnly
FROM Building b
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK. But I've no clue how to transform above query in Linq expression. What's alternate of PatIndex in EF Linq expression? That's my question is.

Comment: `PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', l.BuildingNumber+ 't')` represents the first non numeric character in `I.BuildingNumber`. The `+'t'` causes the expression to return a 1 (instead of 0) when there aren't any numbers in the string.

Answer (score 1):

In the Linq expression you can use `SqlFunctions.PatIndex` and in place of LEFT just use C# string's `.Substring` method - EF should be able to translate it into SQL.